# How to create Time Series Collection with Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, time-series

MongoDB v5.0 introduced a new collection type that is optimized for storing and working with time-series data - [Time Series Collections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/timeseries-collections/). How can we create a Time Series Collection with Mongoose?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It can be done with additional `timeseries` config property when defining the Schema.

```js
const schema = Schema(
  { 
    property_1: String,
    property_2: String,
    timestamp_property: Date, 
    metadata_property: Object,
  {
    timeseries: {
      timeField: 'timestamp_property',
      metaField: 'metadata_property',
      granularity: 'hours',
    },
  }
);
```

- `timeField` is required. It is the name of the field which contains the date in each time series document.
- `metaField` is optional. It is the name of the field which contains metadata in each time series document. The metadata in the specified field should be data that is used to label a unique series of documents. The metadata should rarely, if ever, change.
- `granularity` is optional. Possible values are "**seconds**", "**minutes**", and "**hours**". By default, MongoDB sets the granularity to "**seconds**" for high-frequency ingestion. Manually set the granularity parameter to improve performance by optimizing how data in the time series collection is stored internally. To select a value for granularity, choose the closest match to the time span between consecutive incoming measurements.

---

### Example

Imagine you want to store **Temperature** records for every hour. In that case you would define your schema in the following way:

```js
const schema = Schema(
  {
    calculated_at: Date,
    temperature: Number,
    metadata: {
      sensorId: String,
      location: String,
    },
  },
  {
    timeseries: {
      timeField: 'calculated_at',
      metaField: 'metadata',
      granularity: 'hours',
    },
  }
);
```

Comment: Is the "name" field for the name of the time-series collection in mongo?

Comment: Hi Eric, it is not. It's just some property in the schema model. Let me change that to more generic field name.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying in that fashion. So, if you were recording temperatures, "property_1: String" could be "temperature: Number"? Perhaps you could edit your answer a bit further to provide such an example?

Comment: Yeah, it can. But it's better if you would put it in the `metadata` property. Check here for more info and examples: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/timeseries-collections/. You are right, I will update the answer with an example.

Comment: I noticed in the example where they are doing the "insertMany", the author enters a "temp" field which is not in the metadata.

Comment: Oh, you are completely right! `sensorId` and `type` info were in the `metadata` property. So, you can follow their example and have `temperature: Number` property.

Comment: Sweet! This makes sense now. Thanks for the assist. Updating your example to show all this so it could create a temperature document as they are showing in the mongoose docs would probably benefit many others.

Comment: Yup, will do it. I quickly answered it when I was checking this new time series collection myself. I agree that the answer can be more detailed and to include an example. :D

Comment: Yup, and if you add such a thing, it will be the only thing out on the internet that exists as far as I know since the Mongoose documentation itself is vague and confusing, because I read that before coming here.

Comment: I updated the answer. Can you check it and tell me your opinion? Also I think you have enough reputation to update any answer, so if you think it can be improved, you can update it additionally. :D

Answer (score 1):

The official documentation for creating time series collections with a mongoose schema can be found [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timeseries).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32394696)