# Creating a timeseries collection in mongodb usining mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

MongoDB v5.0 introduced a new collection type that is optimized for storing and working with time-series data - [Time Series Collections](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.3/core/timeseries-collections/).

I've a 3 collection schema:- Datasource, Variables & Values, here is the mongoose schema below for all collections.

```
const DataSourceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

const VariableSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  data_sourceId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "DataSource",
    required: true,
  },
});

const ValueSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  variableId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Variable",
    required: true,
  },
  time: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
  },
  value: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
});
```

I want to create the `values collection` a timeseries collection. How can we create a Time Series Collection with Mongoose?

Any help regarding this will be greatly appreciated. Thankyou

Comment: Reference:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70717856/how-to-create-time-series-collection-with-mongoose