# inserting into a timeseries collection of a database that has not been created yet

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In my APP, there is a need to inert documents on the fly to a timeseries collection in a database that may not exist yet.

If I write a collection that does not exist, mongoDB will create it, but it won't be a timeseries.

How can this be done?

1. The database may not exists yet.
2. So of course, the timeseries collection may not exist yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  documentation states the following directly (emphasis added):

> Before you can insert data into a time series collection, **you must explicitly create the collection** using either the `db.createCollection()` method or the `create` command.

Therefore it sounds like there is no ability to do this built in to the database itself. This suggests you have two options:

1. Add the logic to check for the existence of and, if needed, create the collection before inserting data.
2. Use a client library/ORM that does this for you.

You haven't mentioned which language you are using
but regarding the latter option, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70717856/how-to-create-time-series-collection-with-mongoose) suggests that Mongoose is one library that supports the abstraction/functionality.